# Converting Types in runtime using reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection, casting, runtime

Please take a look at the following code:

```
        var val1 = ExtractValue(firstParam);
        var val2 = ExtractValue(secondParam);

        var type1 = val1.GetType();
        var type2 = val2.GetType();

        TypeConverter converter1 = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(type1);
        TypeConverter converter2 = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(type2);

        if (converter1 != null && converter1.CanConvertFrom(type2))
        {
            var temp = converter1.ConvertFrom(val2);
            return val1.Equals(temp);
        }
        return false;
```

it is a mystery for me that this code does not return true when I try it with a "int" and an Enum object. I even tried "val1.Equals((int)(val2))" in Immediate Window and the result was true but still the converter1.CanConvertFrom(type2) is false.

Could you please help me about it? Is there something that I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: Enum is of type int they are interconvertable.

Comment: You are assuming every type has a [TypeConverter].  This is not the case, only a few do.

Comment: @affan, the default backing type of an Enum is 'int', but it doesn't have to be; it could also be a long, for instance, in which case it could overflow when assigned to an int.

Answer (score 6):

Generalized type conversion is quite poor and inconsistent (in my opinion) in .NET. However for the Enum / int case, you can use the [IConvertible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible.aspx) interface, or the [Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) associated utility class:

```
int converted = (int)Convert.ChangeType(MyEnum.MyValue, typeof(int));
```

or

```
object converted = Convert.ChangeType(myValue, myExpectedType);
```

As a site note, this 100% free library here: [CodeFluentRuntimeClient](http://nuget.org/packages/CodeFluentRuntimeClient)  has a class named `ConvertUtilities` that has a bunch of ChangeType method overloads (including a generic one) that are very versatile and useful for type conversion.

Answer (score 3):

Note the remarks in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92580th5.aspx):

> As implemented in this class, this method always returns `false`. It never returns `true`.

The only time you'll get back a different answer is if you have a derivative of `TypeConverter`. But it's important to note that a lot of the derivatives of `TypeConverter` in the Framework (say `BaseNumberConverter` do NOT override `CanConvertFrom`.